# Create implicit value that causes compilation error on resolution

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

I'm trying to solve i18n problem in Play Framework. I18n requires implicit `Lang` instance to read message from resources. In normal scenario, `Lang` instance is extracted from `Request` via implicit conversion. If there is no `Request` in score, `Lang` becames a `defaultLang` from `Lang` companion object.

In my application, I never want a `defaultLang`. I want correct `Lang`, or a compilation error.

I'm thinking about some `MyI18NSupport` trait, that should block resolution of a `defaultLang` in some way. I'll mix it into my controllers.

Is there any way to create implicit value that causes compilation error on its resolution?

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm assuming something below 2.4 since starting with 2.4, you'll need to pass around a `Messages` object rather than the `Lang`. That `Messages` object will no longer be provided by the `play.api.mvc.Controller`, which means you'll have to mixin `I18nSupport` (which provides an implicit conversion from `Request` to `Messages`) explicitly. Instead, you could mixin your own I18nSupport.